# How to calculate $ \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+\sin(x))\log(\cos(x)) \,dx $?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

How to calculate $$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+\sin(x))\log(\cos(x)) \,dx \,\,?$$
I tried to use the Fourier series of log sine and log cos and I got that the integral is equal to :
$$ \frac{\pi^2}{24}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{k(4k^2-(2n-1)^2)}$$
has anyone a idea to how to find the closed-form of the last series or how to start out differently with the integral?

Comment: Some relevant integrals: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299459/which-function-can-be-used-for-substitution , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890373/log-trig-integral-with-sin-cos-and-tan , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783743/a-beautiful-integral-int-0-pi-2-log-sin-x-log-cos-x-dx?noredirect=1

Comment: With some help from Mathematica, I obtained $$
\frac{\pi }{8}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{4^k k}}\binom{2k}{k}(H_k  + \log 4)}  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{4^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}\frac{1}{{\binom{2k}{k}}}(H_{2k + 1}  - H_k )} .
$$ I do not know if this helps.

Comment: If you make change $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ you will come to the integral type $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+\sin(x))\log(\cos(x)) \,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+\cos(x))\log(\sin(x)) \,dx\sim\int_0^{\pi}\log(2\cos^2(x/2))\log(2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)) \,dx$ Then you will have integrands type $\log(\cos(x))\log(\sin(x))$ - third link provided by @VIVID

Comment: I do apologize - it is not as easy as it looks at first glance. If we change the integrand to $\sim\cos(x/2)\sin(x/2)$ we get very uncomfortable integration limits $(0, \pi/4)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $t=\tan\frac x2$

\begin{align} &\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1+\sin x)\ln(\cos x) \,dx \\
=&\>2\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\frac{(1+t)^2}{1+t^2}\ln \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} }{1+t^2}\,dt
=\>4I_1 +4 I_2 -2I_3- 6I_4+2I_5
\end{align}
where, per the [results](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953815/evaluating-int-01-ln1x2-lnx2x3-fracdx1x2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

\begin{align}
I_1 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+t)\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2} dt
= -G \ln 2-K+\frac{3 \pi ^3}{128}+\frac{3\pi}{32} \ln ^22\\
 I_2 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{1+t^2} dt
= -2 G \ln 2-4 K+\frac{7 \pi ^3}{64}+\frac{3\pi}{16} \ln ^22 \\
I_3 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+t^2)\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2} dt
=  -\frac{1}{2} G \ln 2+4 K -\frac{5 \pi ^3}{64}+\frac{\pi}{8}  \ln ^22 \\
 I_4 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+t^2)\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2} dt
=  -\frac{5}{2} G \ln 2-4 K+\frac{7 \pi ^3}{64}+\frac{3\pi}{8} \ln ^22\\
 I_5 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+t^2)}{1+t^2} dt
= -2 G \ln 2+4 K-\frac{7 \pi ^3}{96}+\frac{7\pi}{8} \ln ^22
\end{align}

with $K= \Im\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)$. Together
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1+\sin x)\ln(\cos x) \,dx 
=4\Im\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)-\frac{11\pi^3}{96}+\frac{3\pi}8\ln^22
$$

Comment: The numerically value is not correct

Comment: @AhmadAlbaw - fixed a couple of typos; should be good now

Comment: Instead $t=\tan(\frac\pi4-\frac x2)$

Comment: Quanto i think you better edit your solution by setting x=(1-x)/(1+x) after you did the half tan subbing. Will look much nicer and simpler

Comment: @AliShadhar - Appreciate the suggestion, which simplifies the integrand considerably and also requires whole-sale changes. It feels almost a different solution. Rather someone posts it as a new answer.

Comment: I agree but no need to make any changes to your solution as you can create addendum section and add your second solution there but its your call of course.

Answer (score 0):

We have a closed form for the inner sum
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{k(4k^2-(2n-1)^2)}$$
$$S_k=(-1)^k \frac{\Phi \left(-1,1,\frac{1}{2}-k\right)-\Phi
   \left(-1,1,\frac{1}{2}+k\right)}{8 k^2}$$ where appears the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function. This can rewrite
$$S_k=(-1)^k \frac{-\psi \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{k}{2}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{k}{2}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{3}{4}\right) }{16 k^2 }$$